# Symbolic Regression Prediction Issue: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, formula

I'm trying to run symbolic regression in R and am using the symbolicRegression and predict functions defined in the rgp package on training and testing data. My training and testing data are both data frames with the same column names. The symbolicRegression function works fine and generates a model. But when I try to predict, I get this error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'AADAC' not found

Here is the code I have written.

```
formula_terms = paste(feature_names, collapse = "+")
form = paste(c(out_name, formula_terms), collapse = "~")
model = symbolicRegression(form, train)
prediction = predict(model, newdata = test)
```

The final formula "form" looks like this:

```
>form
[1] "ABCC12~AADAC+AAK1"
```

Furthermore, "AADAC" is definitely a column name in "test", so I'm not sure why it's not being found.

```
>test[,"AADAC"]
[1] -0.9473086 -0.3793400 -0.5190044 -0.5221080 -0.3917546 -0.4445167  5.1917181
[8] -0.3638217
```

I thought the problem might be that I'm treating "AADAC" as a column name only and not a variable, so I tried this:

```
test$AADAC = test[,"AADAC"]
```

But this didn't fix the problem. Does anyone have an idea why the column name cannot be matched with the correct column in the data frame? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

For reproducibility, here is a subset of the training and test data and the commands for installing and loading rgp:

```
if (!require(devtools)) {
    install.packages("devtools")
    library("devtools")
}
if (!require(rgp)){
    install_github("cran/rgp")
    library("rgp")
}
train = data.frame(c(-0.79541578, -0.57185906,  0.36521617),c( 1.02661507,  0.83108490, -0.61832129),c( -2.45419706,  2.89389899,  0.47570124))
test = data.frame(c( -0.09121212, -0.69295228, 0.26834160),c(-0.9473086, -0.3793400, -0.5190044),c( -0.13091150, 0.07954598, -0.21344385))
colnames(train) = c("ABCC12", "AADAC", "AAK1")
colnames(test) = c("ABCC12", "AADAC", "AAK1")
feature_names = c("AADAC", "AAK1")
out_name = "ABCC12"
```

Comment: The rgp package?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgp/versions/0.4-1. It used to be part of the CRAN repository but is no longer available from CRAN. As far as I know, this is the only package available for symbolic regression in R.

Comment: If you can post a subset of your data so that this problem is reproducible and we can run it on our machines too, it will be a lot easier to provide useful advice. Thanks :)

Comment: @mysteRious Thanks. Just added.

Comment: I do get the same error now, but that package was abandoned by its author 4 years ago and the support website listed in the package DESCRIPTION file is nowhere to be found. `traceback()` results show that the author was using `with` inside his functions and that is a notorious source of errors like this, in that object names get created from column names but then separated from their environments.

Comment: @42 Thanks for following up with this. In that case, it looks like my best option might be to not do this analysis in R.

Comment: I'm not qualified to verify that there is no R package that does whatever the term "symbolic regression" means to you. Such questions are off-topic here but might be on-topic at CrossValidated.com.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for resurrecting a long-dead topic, but I recently came across the very same problem and was able to solve it by modifying the predict() function call Flasch uses inside the main loop. The solution mainly involves removing the with() clause in there. If it still interests you (highly unlikely, but still) I can tell you how.